# Selenium Test Suites

Tags: selenium

I have been running test cases in Selenium IDE using Firefox. This works quite well however when I create a suite by "adding test cases" I can never get the suite to execute. I can't figure out if the problem is with Selenium or me. Any advise for this novice.

Comment: Does only 1 test execute? Or what is the problem? You should have the Test Case list on the left when the suite is open. Then press the Play Entire Test Suite button

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the Test Suites feature before, but when I tried to reproduce your issue I found that saving and then opening a test suite was enough to break it. I was never able to get it to run again. Apparently this is a known issue:

http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SIDE-191

The depressing part is that the bug linked to above was reported in March 2008. I guess Test Suites are not at the top of the priority list. On the other hand, I wouldn't recommend abandoning Selenium completely. If you're comfortable with any of the supported programming languages, simply export your tests and run them with RC. This is a great solution in the long-term because it allows you to add control flow and more sophisticated logic to your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider upgrading to the latest version of Selenium...they're on Version 1.0 as of Jun 30 2009.  Lots of bug fixes, including the 'minor' annoyance of not being able to add new test cases to a test suite via the IDE.

That might help...

Answer (score 0):

Does only 1 test execute? Or what is the problem? You should have the Test Case list on the left when the suite is open. Then press the Play Entire Test Suite button

Comment: Sometimes only the first case executes. Othertime when the play button is pressed the suite does not execute at all. Otherwise, everything is set up as you mentioned.

Comment: There are two play buttons, are you pressing the one with 3 solid green bars, or the one with 2 light green bars and 1 solid green?

Comment: Is this in 'Selenium Test Runner' or the regular IDE window?

Comment: Not sure then, I haven't had any trouble with the IDE window.  As long as all of your tests are set to HTML format, I can't think of anything else. Did you try searching http://clearspace.openqa.org/community/selenium or asking there as well?